# How to enforce no-extend-native in es6 compiled using babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to create a new method to built-in objects Array and Date. I have seen everywhere on the internet that using Object.prototype is evil. Also, I read that subclassing built-in objects is not supported in babel. So how can I add new methods to built-in objects using es6?

Comment: "you can't create subclass by extending built-in classes" is not correct.

Comment: You can do in ES6 everything you can in ES5. You can add methods to a prototype. I do it for polyfills often.

Comment: Your question title does not match your question body.

Comment: @Kulvar You can do in ES6 much more than you can in ES5 - specifically subclassing builtins.

Comment: I said that everything in ES5 is available in ES6, not that ES6 can't do more than ES5

Comment: @stri : One edit, I am using babel to compile ES6 to ES5. Hence, it gives type error if I try to subclass the built-in objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from creating subclasses that extend built-in classes, in fact, it's often a good baseline solution for minor changes.

```js
class Foo extends Date {
  bar() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
```